# How to define shape and scale parameters of selection for testing selection on Pearson Criterion?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, weibull-distribution

I have selection generated by my program. I need to test null hypothesis about accordance to Weibull distribution using Pearson criterion. I stuck on defining alpha(shape) and lambda(scale) parameters of this selection. Is there simple way to define these parameters? May be should I use other method to test this accordance?